# Grab specific values from Slack HTTP response and put into Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm trying to grab specific values from an HTTP response from an interactive Slack component, and post them in specific cells in a Google Sheet.

I think i'm missing something fundamental here, because when I try to run this as intended, nothing is happening.

The actual JSON string looks like this:
(i formatted it online to make it easier to view, and replaced sensitive data with x's)

```
{
   "parameter": {
      "payload": {
         "type": "message_action",
         "token": "xxxxxx",
         "action_ts": "1579669130.303488",
         "team": {
            "id": "xxxx",
            "domain": "xxxxxx"
         },
         "user": {
            "id": "xxxxxx",
            "name": "xxxxx"
         },
         "channel": {
            "id": "xxxxx",
            "name": "privategroup"
         },
         "callback_id": "send to sheets",
         "trigger_id": "xxxx",
         "message_ts": "1579646357.002000",
         "message": {
            "client_msg_id": "xxxxxx",
            "type": "message",
            "text": "<xxxxx> blah",
            "user": "xxxxxx",
            "ts": "1579646357.002000",
            "team": "xxxxx",
            "blocks": [

-It continues on from here-
```

What I want is to grab the "ts" and "user" inside "message"

My code looks like this so far:

```
function doPost(e) {
  if (typeof e !== 'undefined') { 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Escalations');
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    var parsed = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    var userName = parsed.parameter.payload.message.user; 
    var time = parsed.parameter.payload.message.ts; 

    var slackDetails = [time,userName]; 

    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,13,1,2).setValues([slackDetails]);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('thanks');
}
```

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: the documentation states: // The size of the two-dimensional array must match the size of the range. Are you sure that the range is correct?

Comment: 1. May I ask you how you implement that `Slack HTTP response` is being sent to Apps Script project? 2. Is your Apps Script project a WebApp? 3. Why do you implement a `doPost()` and not a `doGet()` function if what you want retrieve data rather than posting it?

Comment: @ziganotschka 1. Not quite sure what you mean? 2. Yes, I've deployed it as a webapp 3. I'm using a doPost() because according to Slack's API docs, interaction payloads will "be sent to your specified request URL in an HTTP POST request."

Comment: Do you know if the `doPost` is even executing? Simplify your example, In your `doPost`, just have it log something like `Logger.log("here");` or maybe `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` and then check the execution logs to see if logs it.

Comment: @str8lac3d: The Slack API posts the data, bu your WebApp receives it. Try to change `doPost` to `doGet` (you need to modify the  event objects accordingly, e.g. `e.parameters` or `e.parameter` instead of `e.postData.contents` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web ). If this does not help - I agree with IMTheNachoMan that you should incorporate logs to see if your function is called at all, and if yes - where it gets stuck.